# How can I make html images fade in on scroll using only javascript (no jquery)?

Tags: javascript, fadein, onscroll

I am working on a university project which requires me to design a website including dynamic Javascript content. This unit is exclusively about Javascript; no Jquery or anything else is allowed until next unit.
What I am trying to accomplish is for the images in the gallery to scroll in when they are scrolled into the viewport. If any part of the image is visible, the script should begin increasing the opacity proportionally to how much of the image has been scrolled in. I've tried a few different things from different tutorial and answers in the stack, but nothing works. The code might work, but it doesn't activate on scroll. Here's the code if anyone can help:

```
var elementPosition = window.pageYOffset;
    
function isInViewport(img) {
  var relct = img.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  return rect.bottom > 0 && 
  rect.right > 0 && 
  rect.left < (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) &&
  rect.top < (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
  
}

function fadeIn() {
  var imgList = document.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < imgList.length; i++) {
    var img = imgList[i];
    if (isInViewport(img)) {
      if (elementPosition < 200) {
        opacity = 1 - (elementPosition / 200));
      }
      else {
        opacity = 1;
      }    
    }
    else {
      opacity = 0;
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', fadeIn());
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of typos were fouling your code -- I'd recommend using an application that will either tidy your code and/or flag errors as you write (personally, I use codepen.io). Also, opacity is set by: `element.style.opacity`.

```js
var imgList = document.getElementsByTagName("IMG");

function isInViewport(img) {
  var rect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    rect.bottom > 0 &&
    rect.right > 0 &&
    rect.left < (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) &&
    rect.top < (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
  );
}

function fadeIn() {
  for (i = 0; i < imgList.length; i++) {
    if (isInViewport(imgList[i])) {
      imgList[i].style.opacity = 1;
    }
  }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", fadeIn);
```

```css
img {display: block; transition: all 1s; opacity: 0;}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/300/600">
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/300/600">
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/300/600">
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/300/600">
```